# Sending object as a parameter to POST in axios won't work

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to send a post request in VUE.JS using axios but there's an issue.

I have this TEST object set up in data

```
data () { return { test:{ name: 'foo', surname: 'bar' } }; },
```

And here's my method

```
testMethod() {

  axios.post('url',this.test)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

It won't work. It's sending an empty object to my API. If I try this, it works

```
testMethod(){

  axios.post('url',{'name':'foo', 'surname': 'bar'})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Any idea on what's wrong?

Not sure if that's a bug or not.

Comment: Might be the same issue as: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/738

Comment: @M.Suurland I think not, man. By looking at my response.request I can see it's really sending an empty string.

Comment: And if you `console.log(this.test)` right before the `axios.post`, you see the proper data?

Comment: @patricksteele yes!

Comment: Must be something else in your code.  Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psteele/ndv4nued/) showing an axios post from a Vue component and it sends the data without a problem.

Comment: @PatrickSteele What if the test id an array of Objects and you want to make post request now. For me it is giving 500 internal error and not even trigger the method which I am pointing to

Comment: @JustStartedProgramming Please open a new question and post the relevant code you're having problems with.

Comment: @PatrickSteele I did that but nobody answers it up till now

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the scope of the variables, You are using the word "this", but its value depends on where is called.
Declare a variable to ensure you are referring the object you want

```
methods: {
  testMethod() {
    //Ensure that you are referring to the Vue Object
    var vm = this;
    axios.post('url',vm.test)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```